# PHP Azure OCR - convert JSON in Array

Tags: php, arrays, json, azure, ocr

I'm using Azure OCR Service, now I would like to save the data I get in an array. 
Unfortunately I always get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in XXX on line 43
```

My output ist:

```
{"language":"en","textAngle":-2.5000000000000346,"orientation":"Up","regions":[{"boundingBox":"896,2104,1528,688","lines":[{"boundingBox":"896,2104,1528,688","words":[{"boundingBox":"896,2104,1528,688","text":"DFG"}]}]}]}
```

My code is:

```
    $request->setHeader($headers);
    $parameters = array(
        // Request parameters
        'language' => 'unk',
        'detectOrientation ' => 'true',
    );

    $url->setQueryVariables($parameters);
    $request->setMethod(HTTP_Request2::METHOD_POST);   
    $body = array('url' => 'https://i.imgur.com/2sUbQC8.jpg');
    $request->setBody(json_encode($body));

    // Request body


    try
    {
        $response = $request->send();
        echo $response->getBody();
        $json = json_decode($response, true);

    }
    catch (HttpException $ex)
    {
        echo "Fehler :(";
        echo $ex;
    }

?>
```

Comment: Try `$json = json_decode($response->getBody(), true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `echo $response->getBody();`
Instead, assign it to a variable:

`$json = $response->getBody();`

Then you can turn it into an array:

`$array = json_decode($json, true);`